# Openthread communcation setup

Tags: texas-instruments, zigbee, openthread, simplicity-studio

I have implemented OT-CLI-FTD communication between two EFR32MG12 MCUs using the command line terminal, but now how could I handle it without the command line terminal for its initial setups. So that I could implement it in the MCUs themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenThread CLI makes calls to the [OpenThread API](https://openthread.io/reference). You can use that as a reference to what OpenThread APIs you need to call.

We have a [Developing with OpenThread APIs](https://openthread.io/codelabs/openthread-apis#0) codelab. At the same time, many [OpenThread platforms](https://openthread.io/platforms) include examples in their SDKs.